# How to subclass a ListView with XAML set CachingStrategy in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am setting the `CachingStrategy` of my own `ListView` inherited subclass in a XAML file.

But because the `CachingStrategy` has a private setter and because it is set using the `Parameter` attribute in one of it's constructors, which for some reason is declared as internal and sealed, there seems to be no way to subclass a `ListView`.

The following compiler error is generated:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'CachingStrategy', or mismatching type between value and property.

Is this intentional? What's the reason for the `Parameter` attribute to be internal and more importantly, is there a clean way to subclass a `ListView`?

As a workaround, I ended up doing the following, which works:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public new ListViewCachingStrategy CachingStrategy
    {
        get => base.CachingStrategy;
        set => GetType().BaseType.GetProperty(nameof(CachingStrategy))
                        .SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to subclass ListView and set the caching strategy from XAML, but it isn't straightforward. The documentation is here on it:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/#Setting_the_Caching_Strategy_in_a_Subclassed_ListView

The important thing is that the caching strategy must be passed into the constructor, which is probably why there is no way to set it using a property.

The relevant pieces of code to subclass ListView and use from XAML are copied from the Xamarin docs here:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
  public CustomListView (ListViewCachingStrategy strategy) : base (strategy)
  {
  }
  ...
}
```

Then consuming that in your XAML:

```
<local:CustomListView>
  <x:Arguments>
    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
  </x:Arguments>
</local:CustomListView>
```

Not as elegant as when using the base class, sadly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Not very elegant, but good enough combined with an explaining comment in the XAML code.